# Navbar always pushes from the right when resizing width of window

Tags: html, css

I'm sorta new to web development. My navbar seems to have this problem where anytime I resize the width of the window it edges off to the right. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY4QD.jpg
I'm not sure if its the method I used to make the nav or something internal that's only happening to my system, but anyway;
How would I fix this?.

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*Navigation Bar*/
nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    font-family:'Nunito', sans-serif;
    background-color: #49e949;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #535353dc;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-links{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.nav-links a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 1rem 5rem;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.2s;
}
.nav-links a:hover{
    color: #49e949;
    background-color: #ddfddd;
}

.nav-links .active-page{
    color: #49e949;
    background-color: #ddfddd;
}

/*Content*/
.container{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    margin: 0;
    left: 44%;
}

.count-container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.count-container div{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.count-number{
    font-size: 50px;
    margin: 0px 40px;
}

/*Arrows*/
.add-arrow{
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid #4667fa;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

.subtract-arrow{
    border-top: 25px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid #ff3333;
    border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}
/*Arrows End*/

.reset{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 2px solid black;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.reset:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/counter.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="index.html">Colour Switcher</a></li>
            <li><a href="counter.html" class="active-page">Counter</a></li>
            <li><a href="sidebar.html">Sidebar</a></li>
            <li><a href="modal.html">Modal</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="count-container">
            <div class="subtract-arrow" id="subtract-arrow"></div>
            <h1 class="count-number" id="count-number">0</h1>
            <div class="add-arrow" id="add-arrow"></div>
        </div>
        <button class="reset" id="reset">reset</button>
    </div>

    <!--Javascript-->
    <script src="js/counter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By default, `overflow` is `visible`, so any content that overflows will be visible, adding scrollbars to the screen where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your `padding: 1rem 5rem;` property inside of `.nav-links a` is pushing your links outside of their container when the size of the navbar decreases in width. W3C defines a rem unit as:

> Equal to the computed value of font-size on the root element.

In most browsers this computed value is equal to 16px so 5rem is actually pretty large. This means that there is 160px of combined padding between each of your links. So you could go with 1 or 2 rem instead and that will give you a lot more leeway as far as when elements will start getting pushed out of their container relative to screen size.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the width of your links are at a set width due to padding on each link which is set here in your CSS:

```
.nav-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 1rem 5rem;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

The width of your page isn't going to change the padding of those links, unless you tell it to. You can use media-queries to change the padding to be smaller when the page reaches a certain width like this:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .nav-links a {
    padding: 1rem 2rem;
  }
}
```

Be sure to put this media query at the bottom of your CSS stylesheet.

You can read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

Comment: The media query at 900 isn’t really necessary because he already has justify content set to space around, so the elements aren’t ever in any danger of touching each other until they get to a mobile sized window, at which point he would want to change the layout of the navbar completely.

Comment: He can use media queries to change the layout of the navbar as you said, so with my answer, I'm helping him solve the issue, while also showing him a feature he can use for later functionality.